# How do I get the contents of the library in Java?

Tags: java, native

How do I check the contents of a native library. I have gone this far:

```
try {
    System.load("/path/to/my/native/libraries/library.so");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
}
```

What is left for me is to start using the library right? Thus the question, how do I get the contents of the library?

More Info:
        Language: Java
        OS: Ubuntu 10.04, Linux

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the *binary* contents of the file?

Comment: No! I am trying to use a native library. I have loaded it but I cant use it. I thought that for me to use it, I have to know whats in it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (JNI). It facilitates access to native code from Java. You may want to take a look at "[The Java Native Interface
Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html)" to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'd look into it.

Answer (score 2):

[JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) provides an easier way to use libraries that where not built for JNI (with JNI you always need some Java-specific code).